# How can I upload to GitHub through Putty?

Tags: github, putty, uploading, codebase

I'm very new to GitHub and I'm trying to figure out how I can upload to GitHub through Putty. I am using Windows 8 and am using a Linux environment through Putty. I was following this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys#platform-windows and it worked until (step 3) where it wanted me to copy the contents of the file to clipboard. I am assuming this is not possible because my Linux environment does not have clipboard.

The issue is mostly due to the fact that my code is on the linux envirnonment and I am not sure how I can upload it to GitHub. Does anyone have any advice as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cat the file out, and copy the contents from the putty session (just highlighting the text in putty will copy it to your clipboard):

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Make sure to remove any new lines inserted caused by putty wrapping the text.

Answer (score 0):

You will have an easier time using MinGW on Windows, or even the Github for Windows client (the latter works "out of the box")

If using **MinGW**, I would recommend opening `C:\Users\YourUserName\.ssh\id_rsa.pub` in a text editor, such as sublime text, and copying the text, instead of using `cat`, because that will ensure that you do not get extra whitespace inserted by the shell (Windows command prompt is pretty bad with that sort of thing).

If using the **Github for Windows** client, you don't need to do any of this (it happens behind the scenes for you), and instead you simply need to login to your Github account in the client.